# Julia abbreviation for index set of array

Tags: multidimensional-array, julia

Consider two matrices of different size

```
julia> A= ones(Float64,3,3)
3×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 1.0  1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0  1.0

julia> B = ones(Float64,2,2)
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0
```

Is there a shorthand notation for

```
julia> A[1:size(B)[1],1:size(B)[2]]
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0
```

in the form of a nice function like "`julia> A[indices(B)]`" (which unfortunately does not exist `ERROR: UndefVarError: indices not defined`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call `axes(B)` to get a tuple containing the valid indices for `B`:

```
julia> A = ones(3, 3)
3×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 1.0  1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0  1.0

julia> B = ones(2, 2)
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0

julia> axes(B)
(Base.OneTo(2), Base.OneTo(2))
```

Thus, you can unpack the tuple and use it for indexing `A`:

```
julia> A[axes(B)...]
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0
```

As Bogumil Kaminski pointed out in the comments, you can also use `CartesianIndices`:

```
julia> A[CartesianIndices(B)]
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0
```

Comment: or `A[CartesianIndices(B)]`